# Iterating over matches from preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, foreach, preg-match-all

I am trying to figure out the mechanics of this plugin in WordPress.
I have a preg_match_all function that looks like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\\[\\[).+?(?=\\]\\])/', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$numMatches = count($matches[0]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numMatches; $i++) {
  $postSlug = $matches[0][$i];
}
```

If I understand this correctly, `count($matches[0])` assumes there is only one match in `$content`.

My goal here is to re-write the for statement to allow for the full array of matches in the `preg_match_all` script.

I'm assuming I should replace the for statement with `foreach ($matches as $postSlug)` and not even bother with the confusing `$matches[0][$i]` at the end.

Unfortunately the final output does not seem to loop through each element in the array. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I understand this correctly, count($matches[0] assumes there is only one match in $content.

Not quite; `$matches[0]` represents the array of matches in of the whole regular expression (as opposed to, say, `$matches[1]`, which would be the array of matches in the first match group of the regular expression).  Thus, `count($matches[0])` is the number of matches in he first match group.

You could do what you've said and rewrite the `for` loop as a `foreach` loop, but this likely won't change anything, as both methods should traverse all elements in `$matches[0]`.  Are you certain that the results you're looking for are matched in your regular expression?

Comment: You're right. $matches[0] refers to the array of matches in the whole expression. I was able to loop through the array successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to rewrite this code, then I suggest you look into [`PREG_SET_ORDER`](http://php.net/PREG_MATCH_ALL) as last argument, instead of `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`. This groups the result array by results first, and with match groups in the second level.

Then you can just loop over it as follows:

```
foreach ($matches as $matchgroup) {
    $postslug = $matchgroup[0];
}
```

You still need the `[0]` to get the "complete match". If your pattern had any `(..)` groups then `[1]` and `[2]` would correspond to those..